# Creating single SQLite table instead of multiple while inserting excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, sqlite

I have an excel sheet that I would like to add to a Database. The Excel sheet has several columns of data: One for the Date, one for the Time, and several for number counts.
Currently, I am inserting the data with the following python code:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

conn = sqlite3.connect('DatabaseTest.db')

spreadsheetFile = "data.xls"
dataset = pd.read_excel(spreadsheetFile, sheetname = None, skiprows = 6)
for sheet in dataset:
    wb[sheet].to_sql(sheet, conn, index = False)

conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

In line 7 I have the skiprows function because the sheet starts with some info about the sensor that is irrelevant to the measurement.

When I execute the code, it inserts the data into the dataset, but it creates a table for each column instead of creating a single table for all columns. What do I need to change/add to solve this?

Comment: BTW I followed this tutorial: [https://scientificpythonsnippets.com/index.php/2-uncategorised/3-convert-excel-file-into-sql-database]